# Magento 2.1.8 is taking too much time to load

Tags: magento2, pagespeed

We just developed our website with Magento 2.1.8 but it takes time to load.

http://megabooklet.com/beta/

Can someone please tell where is the lag?

Comment: A quick run through https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ shows that you can save a lot on your images (use smaller sized images (compress them)), minifying your CSS and JS and as Bare Feet says: use Varnish and enable all your cache!

Comment: Also your admin url should not be `/admin` and you need https.

Comment: Although it is not recommended by Magento to have `/admin`, I do not recommend changing your admin URI – security through obscurity is not security. Keeping the `/admin` URL allows for us to automatically apply WAF rules to protect the admin, allows us to auto tag admin requests, prioritise, set memory limits and timeouts and pass requests as necessary. So rather than creating a obscure admin path, I recommend protecting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This steps is useful for improve page speed-up.

1. Enable GZIP compression.
2. Use Lazy Loading for images.
3. Keep your Magento and 3rd party extensions up to date.
4. Use sprite image instead of separate images of small icons.

I hope this will useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

Install and configure Varnish, it has massive impact on performance of the store.

Varnish Cache is an open source web application accelerator (also referred to as an HTTP accelerator or caching HTTP reverse proxy). Varnish stores (or caches) files or fragments of files in memory; this enables Varnish to reduce the response time and network bandwidth consumption on future, equivalent requests. Unlike web servers like Apache and nginx, Varnish was designed for use exclusively with the HTTP protocol.

Follow this link for more information: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html

Also, make sure that cache are always **Enabled** in production environment.